# Laravel - How to send data from a checkbox button to a controller using Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller, send

I am trying to have a toggle button (checkbox) changing some data in my MySQL database. I essentially want to to have a nice admin site in which I can unlock users to certain features on the site with a nice on/off switch.

Everything seems to be set up correctly, but my controller doesn't react or get triggered at all.

Right now, I have a working toggle button in my view triggering a javascript function. In that javascript function, I have already set up data that I want to transmit over to my controller.

I have also set up Ajax in my Javascript. Apparently Ajax has this part in its code (see my code if you need to know what I mean) where it says "success" or "error". Before entering the {{csrf_token()}} token, I always ended up in the error section. However, now I always enter the "success" section when toggling my button.

Now to my problem:
Although Ajax confirms a success, literally nothing happens within my controller. I have no idea how to change this as there is no error code whatsoever, either.

This is my button

```
<input id = "company_{{$company->id}}" data-id="{{$company->id}}" onchange=myFunction({{$company->id}}) value = {{$company->permissionlevel}} class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $company->permissionlevel ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

This is my javascript (the relevant part)

```
var test = 12; // A random variable for this example

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
            url: 'home/update', // This is the url we gave in the route
            data: {'test' : test, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'}, // a JSON object to send back
            success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                console.log(response); 
                //alert("Ajax success");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                //alert("Ajax error");
            }
        });
```

This is my controller function (just to see what happens)

```
public function update (Request $request)
    {

            //echo "This is a test";
            $data = $request->all(); // This will get all the request data.
            dd($data); // This will dump and die
            return $data;



        }
```

Route

```
Route::post('/home/update', 'HomeController@update');
```

Expected result:
Controller throws something at me. Currently all I want is to see if my controller reacts to the button press or if I can request the data Ajax is supposed to send over.

Actual result:
Nothing happens on my controller's side

Comment: What do the console and network tab in your inspector show?

Comment: {test: "12", _token: "mssayxmlw6k3t8IZrIz5WUGMZYLjThFKXuSeCRJk"}
test: "12"
_token: "mssayxmlw6k3t8IZrIz5WUGMZYLjThFKXuSeCRJk"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Telling by how the console output looks like, I assumed something does in fact happen. However, the console gets flooded with errors if I enter the wrong things on my controller. $test = $request->input('value');   followed by an   echo $test; works just fine and I get the actual output of that on my console. However, something simple like $user->save(); throws a ton of errors at me, so does anything like $user->id = 5; This command even throws a full console of errors

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by myself. I essentially added this code to my **controller**:

```
public function update (Request $request, $id, User $user)
{
$newPermLevel = $request->input('value');
    $override = (int) $newPermLevel;

    \DB::table('users')->where('id',$id)->update(array(
       'permissionlevel'=>$override,
     ));
}
```

However, I need to add these small lines at the beginning of my controller right behind the namespace:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
```

Just for completion, I will leave the other necessary code here as well for anybody in the need to update his database with a toggle / switch button

Here's my **route**

```
Route::post('/home/update/{id}', 'HomeController@update');
```

Here's my **HTML**
based on the current state of a button, I make an if statement (using blade engine) either creating a turned off or  turned on switch. The button has a value, which essentially is the current database entry (in my case it is either 1 or 0 that I want to jump up and forth with)

```html
@if ($company->permissionlevel == 0)
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label class="switch">
  <input id = "company_{{$company->id}}" data-id="{{$company->id}}" onchange=myFunction({{$company->id}}) value = {{$company->permissionlevel}} class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $company->permissionlevel ? 'checked' : '' }}>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
   </label>
</div>
@endif @if ($company->permissionlevel == 1)
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label class="switch">
  <input id = "company_{{$company->id}}" data-id="{{$company->id}}" onchange=myFunction({{$company->id}}) value = {{$company->permissionlevel}} class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $company->permissionlevel ? 'checked' : '' }}>
    <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</div>
@endif
```

At last, my **Javascript** making use of Ajax. The code essentially check if the value of out switch is currently on 0 (then switch it to 1) or on 1 (then switch it to 0). Additionally, I define a variable to grab the current user's (company's ID), so that the controller later on knows to which user I refer.

```js
<script>
  function myFunction(id) {
 
        var value = document.getElementById("company_" + id).value;
        

        if (value == 1){
            document.getElementById("company_" + id).value = 0;
            //alert(document.getElementById("company_" + id).value);
        }
        if (value == 0){         
            document.getElementById("company_" + id).value = 1;
            //alert(document.getElementById("company_" + id).value);
        }
    
        var company_id = id;
        var newPermLevel = document.getElementById("company_" + id).value;


        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
            url: 'home/update/'+company_id, // This is the url we gave in the route
            data: {
            'company_id' : company_id, 
            'value' : newPermLevel,
            _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
            
            },
             // a JSON object to send back
            success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
                console.log(response); 
                //alert("Ajax success");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // What to do if we fail
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
                //alert("Ajax error");
            }
        });

        
    }
</script>
```

Consider this question closed, but thanks for reading along. I hope anybody googling desperately for a similar solution can make use of my code. **Not all heroes wear capes :)**